# Removing an unwanted part of an external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xss, user-tracking

I actually load an external JavaScript on my page this way:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://somedomain.com/somescript.php'></script>
```

*Note: it is a PHP file, but it produces and gives back a JavaScript code*

However, there are two parts of the script - this is the first one, which I need:

```
document.getElementById('latest').innerHTML= "the lastest version of product";
```

And here is the second, which is unwanted, and I need to get rid of it:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://somedomain.com/tracking.php";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(img);
```

How can I get rid of this one image, which tracks users, before it will send the data, but leave the showing of the lastest version intact without changes.

Comment: It's not going to be easy. You'd have to AJAX load the script as text, parse the text to remove (or neuter) the image tracker, and, then `eval()` the result. Seems very fragile.

Comment: @dave: It won't do to remove the added element after the script has executed. By that time the image tracker will have already collected its information. You have to prevent the image from being added to the DOM in the first place.

Comment: @dave: How can I remove the appended item then?

Comment: Yeah I missed that part. As far as loading via Ajax I don't think that will work because of CORS. Possibly a server-side proxy would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Michael's solution, it should be possible to prevent the javascript from executing by running some code first.  If you run the following before adding the script:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild = function() {};
```

Their script will be unable to add the image to the dom.  If you need to use that method for yourself, assign it to a different variable first.  Or try:

```
var oldMethod = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild;
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild = function(node) {
    if (node.src !== "http://somedomain.com/tracking.php") {
        oldMethod(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what others suggested - cause the unwanted script part to fail, but using a cleaner "block", we can snatch the `img` identifier and prevent it from being used. We do that be using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), which, by default creates a non-configurable, non-writable property.

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'img', {value: null}); // this snatches the identifier

img = document.createElement('img'); // <- this won't work

alert(img); // <- this is null
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it would work and it's a hack, but you could try it with a `try catch` and `const`. `const` might work on firefox and chrome, you'd need a [polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) for safari and older browsers.

```
<script>
const img = '';
try {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://somedomain.com/somescript.php';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
} catch (err) {}
</script>
```

By defining the global const it should throw an error when the variable is assigned, then we handle the error by doing nothing with it, so the part before the error was thrown should still be loaded without interrupting the rest of the script.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have constants (yet)

Comment: Yes, it does have [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), it part of ES6

Comment: It does, but its new (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).  Won't support browsers older than IE 11.

Comment: That's true, I made that clearer in the answer. @JamesBrierley

Comment: I still see the unwanted image - I am using Chrome 47 canary

Answer (score 0):

I alluded to this in my comments, but I think the only way to achieve what you ask is to AJAX load the script (if the server permits it) and parse out the offending code. That seems overly complex and error-prone, and borderline unethical. I would suggest that you contact the host of the script `somedomain.com` and ask if they can provide a version without the image tracker. If they decline, then you should respect their wishes. After all, it is their content (the first part of the script) that you want, and they have every right to specify your obligations to use it. If you don't like their terms, don't use their content.

(BTW, I'm not suggesting that image trackers are a good thing. I despise them.)

Comment: It is their CMS and update-checking script. However, it does also unwanted things around. Also, there was not anything in the license that permits them to track me on my own server through their scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS?

```
<head>
<style>
    img[href *= "somedomain.com/tracking.php"] {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="yourscript"></script>
</body>
```

Key factor here is that browsers will ignore images, which are hidden. Thus you need to move the external script to the body.

Analytics providers tend to put themselves on top of everything (head), but there is no real reason  for that 99.9% of the time. They just feel very important.

Comment: You just hide the tracking image. You will not stop sending the data with this (at least in Chrome 47).